# sourcing vimrc when opening a file in tab page?

Tags: vim

I have a the following in my vimrc to highlight any lines that go past 80 columns:

```
highlight ColorColumn ctermfg=red ctermbg=bg
call matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%81v.\+', 100)
```

It works great in most cases. However, I've noticed that if i open a file in a new tab, it doesn't work at all. I'm able to fix this by `:source $MYVIMRC`. But the issue is, when I source my vimrc I lose my indentLines plugin. I've done a little testing, and I have found that the indentLines goes away anytime the `vimrc` is sourced in an open instance of vim. Still, I am unable to determine why the 2 lines shown above are not being called when I open a file in a new tab. Any ideas?

**[my vimrc](https://gist.github.com/ndland/9257147)**

Comment: May want to check out `:set cc=81`. See `:h 'cc'` for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `matchadd()` only affects the current window. In order to have it on all windows you can add the following to your .vimrc:

```
if exists("*matchadd")
   augroup colorColumn
      au!
      au BufEnter * call matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%81v.\+', 100)
   augroup END
endif
```

---

Edit: As pointed by Ingo on the comments, the `BufEnter` will trigger many times when it is not necessary. The lines below correct this issue:

```
if exists("*matchadd")
   augroup colorColumn
      au!
      au VimEnter,WinEnter * call matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%81v.\+', 100)
   augroup END
endif
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I figured it might have something to do with that, but wasn't sure how to get around it.

Comment: `WinEnter` would be more appropriate, as (in your own words), `matchadd()` is window-scoped. You'd need `VimEnter`, too, as it doesn't fire for the very first window.

Comment: @NicholasLand: I’m glad I was able to help.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: I've indeed wrote `WinEnter` on the first version and I've noticed it didn't fire on the initial window. Without further investigation I've changed to `BufEnter`. Thanks for your help!